# How to associate Call Flow to Phone Number using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cli, amazon-connect

In Amazon Connect, there is a way to associate a Contact Flow to a Phone Number (the first call flow executed when the phone number is called).

This CLI call to do that is [associate-phone-number-contact-flow](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/connect/associate-phone-number-contact-flow.html).

Is there a way to create this association using Terraform?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this using Hashicorp's AWS provider at the moment.

Here's a [feature request](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/26015) to implement this functionality.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I did not know there was a feature request out for this functionality.